# Inter-Service Communication between Microservices between Inventory and Order Microservice

Tags: microservices

I have two microservices - Inventory and Order. The Inventory Microservice manages the quantity of specific products, while the Order Microservice handles customer orders. When orders are placed, a message is sent via Apache Kafka Message Queue to the Inventory Microservice to decrease the quantity of the ordered product. Before sending the message to reduce the quantity, I need to retrieve the current product quantity. What would be the best approach for this?

My current approach is as follows:

1. Retrieve the inventory quantity through gRPC communication. In the Inventory Microservice, implement a database transaction to fetch the inventory quantity and send this information back to the Order Microservice.
2. In the Order Microservice, if the ordered quantity is less than the inventory quantity, we send an event via Apache Kafka to the Inventory Microservice to update the inventory count.

Is this approach suitable? Or, how can I improve it and are there any potential problems that could arise? I want to avoid race conditions and avoid having negative inventory quantity.

[image]

Comment: Yea, you can end up with negative inventory, since you have a time period between checking the current inventory and actually decreasing the inventory. There are several ways to avoid this, so this might be opinion-based.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I ended up reserving quantity in my stock and locking the order from being modified by the user while the order is being processed.

Comment: @zoran404 Oh yeah you are right, I might still end up with negative inventory. Regarding your proposed solution, do you mean setting a lock (database lock? or Mutex?) in the quantity in the Inventory Microservice? If there is sufficient quantity, we decrement the quantity. If there is insufficient quantity, we don't decrement it. Whatever the result is - decrement or don't decrement, we publish a message back to Order Microservice stating the result.

Comment: There may be better solutions than what I use, but here is my very simple solution: I'd put a timestamp in the db item and remove the timestamp when I'm done. The way this prevents 2 functions from modifying the same item is that I only set a new timestamp if there is no timestamp in the db or if the timestamp in db is older than a couple of seconds. This "couple of seconds" timeout is so I can ignore the lock if the previous function call had an error and failed to remove it. That case should never happen, but is nice to have as a fail-safe.